# Problem with Luma theme magento 2

Tags: magento2, theme, magento-2.0

I installed Luma theme with sample data .The icons are corrupted and do not allow click
https://www.magentocommerce.com/download

p / s : I've previously installed a beta in https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/1.0.0-beta . It worked . Now I set the official version has happened problem

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First reindex all data
after refress or flush cache
if not done then after do follow:

This is occurred because of static content deploy.
You must have to open your installation/bin folder.
After that click hold shift+ mouse right click.
now,popup menu open which you can see in image.
than click on the "Open command window here" option.
after that command prompt open which have your folder path.
after than hit command "php magento setup:static-content:deploy" and hit enter.
wait until process done.
if any kind of error not occur then your icon visible at both the ends "frontend" and "backend":
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just because I ran into this, and although PG Sutariya kind of hits it right it is a little system specific, the basic answer is to use

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

from the magento install directory.

Answer (score 0):

Check permission directories 755 and files 644, also flush your cache, and reindex

> bin/magento cache:clean
>
> bin/magento indexer:reindex